# In Jekyll, I want to loop through items in a list and set assign tags for each item

Tags: jekyll

In Jekyll, I want to loop through items in a list and assign variables to each of them.

In a data file, my list looks like this:

```
entries:
- title: Sidebar
  subcategories:
    - title: Overview
      items:
        - title: Introduction
          url: /introduction/
          linkname: intro

        - title: Release Notes
          url: /release_notes/
          linkname: relnote
```

My looping logic looks like this:

```
{% for entry in sidebar %}
  {% for subcategory in entry.subcategories %}
    {% for item in subcategory.items %}
      {% assign item.linkname = "<a href="{{ /item.permalink | prepend: site.baseurl}}">{{item.title}}</a>" %}
    {% endfor %}
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Then I want to insert the variable using {{intro}} or {{relnote}} on a page. Using this method, I should be able to generate variables for all the items in my sidebar, making it easy to embed links in my content.

However, this method doesn't seem to work. Nothing appears for the variable when I insert it. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Jekyll/Liquid, you cannot create a variable name from a variable value.

Comment: Thanks, David. BTW, I found your test cases for Jekyll ([http://jekyll.pygmeeweb.com/tests/](http://jekyll.pygmeeweb.com/tests/)) really helpful. one thing i didn't understand, however, is how to add items to an array. i asked this question on [jekyll talk here](https://talk.jekyllrb.com/t/how-do-you-add-items-to-an-array-in-jekyll/324) but never got an answer. i think the answer might be helpful in solving the problem here as well. can you point out where i'm going wrong? thanks.

Comment: I've answered on Jekyll talk.